# Why is “resolved” used ahead of a question in a debate title, instead of saying “the Subject, topic” or alike?

Tags: word-choice

I’m now reading a book titled “Competitive Debate – The Official Guide” by Richard E. Edward. In it, there is the following sentence:

The topic for public forum debate are selected by a comitee of the NFL. --- Some public forum topics have been resolutions of fact: “**Resolved**: The United States is losing the War on Terror.” Some topics have been solution value: “**Resolved**: The costs of legalized casino gambling in the U.S. outweigh the benefits” “**Resolved**: The United States should issue guest worker visas to illegal aliens.”

In all of the above examples, for what meaning is “Resolved” used? I gusess “Resolved” means “Question to be resolved.” But I don’t understand why it (Resolve) is used in past participle form, not in noun form, and why not using a word like “the debate subject” “theme”, “issue”,“agenda” or even “Resolution required”?

Comment: I find the form a bit strange, too.  It's important to note that the form is intentionally asymmetric: it isn't saying "here's the topic we'll discuss", it's stating a position for people to either agree with or disagree with.

Comment: Definitely more American usage than anything else! I daresay nowhere else in the English-speaking world is this used. You're more likely to here *motion*, etc, elsewhere.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: In the UK you're more likely to see "This house believes..." as the debate title.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Cool. I guess it's not too difficult to see how "This house believes..." and "Resolved..." are related. And I meant to type "hear", by the way. (Embarrassing error!)

Comment: I don't know about this forum, but on lots of technical forums **solved** or **resolved** attached to a topic with a question mean the answer to the question has been found. These seeking to help others need not visit such questions, these seeking answers won't find them in topics without such a tag.

Comment: @SF some 'further reading' on these lines would be very nice.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The opposing teams are preemptively declaring victory.

"Our reasoning is such that our position is the only logical one. You guys may as well not even bother with your weak and ineffectual arguments."

Comment: I don't think that's really what it means...that would be really snarky. I think it's just a way of framing an argument with a simple proposition that can be debated affirmatively or negatively. It is the "resolution" of the discussion.

Comment: I also disagree, for slightly different reasons. It's simply the application of *Robert's Rules of Order* to formal debate. It's become second nature to start any debate with "Resolved" even if technically, you're not putting forth a resolution, but simply a topic or thesis for discussion.

Comment: In a logical process, you have not "resolved" an issue until all aspects have been considered and compared. I think mine is a reasonable interpretation, although it may very well not be the origin of the usage here. My observation is that formal debaters can be among the snarkiest - even outside the arena. In a formal debate, they are not attempting to reach the truly best conclusion, rather the one they have predetermined (or been assigned) to consider correct. They "have an agenda". If anything, their snarkiness supports this view of usage. A formal debate is empathically NOT a discussion.

Comment: Mickeyf. 'Resolved' because each team is declaring victory, it sounds reasonable. Still it sounds logically odd to me that the agenda is given in the form of'past tense' by NFL (National Forensic League before the question (theme, issue, whatever) being resolved. - Yoichi

Comment: @Yoichi It sounds reasonable, but it's wrong. *Resolved* in a formal debate context is *not* used to sound confident or snarky. It's tradition, based on formal rules of debate.

Answer (score 16):

As per Bartelby's:

> In 1876 General Henry M. Robert set out to bring the rules of the American Congress to members of ordinary societies with the publication of [Pocket Manual of Rules of Order](http://www.bartleby.com/176/). It sold half a million copies before this revision of 1915 and made Robert’s name synonymous with the orderly rule of reason in deliberative societies.

In [Chapter 4](http://www.bartleby.com/176/4.html):

> When a main motion is of such importance or length as to be in writing it is usually written in the form of a resolution; that is, beginning with the words, “Resolved, That,” the word “Resolved” being underscored (printed in italics) and followed by a comma, and the word “That” beginning with a capital “T.”

So, because *Robert’s Rules of Order* have been a popular framework for American "deliberative societies" they have been adapted and applied to formal debate, so much so that *Resolved* has become the go-to word to begin your thesis.

Comment: Thank you Ghoppe for providing me an excerpt from Robert's rule book for debate. So it's not an issue of grammar i.e. tense of verb, but how to frame it. Right? - Yoichi

Comment: @Yoichi Exactly. Since you are putting forth a *resolution* that is what is "resolved."

Comment: When I learned Robert's Rules of Order ages ago (they actually taught that in high school!), I learned that "resolved" is short for "be it resolved" -- this statement is the proposition that we will debate and vote on.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That is correct, but technically the "be it" part is the last words of the preamble. See the Chapter 4 link above which states: *The preamble should never contain a period, but each paragraph should close with a comma or semicolon, followed by “and,” except the last paragraph, which should close with the word “therefore,” or “therefore, be it.”*

Answer (score 3):

It's just a way of announcing a topic (i.e. a resolution) which will be debated. According to Wikipedia:

> In policy debate, a resolution or
>   topic is a normative statement which
>   the affirmative team affirms and the
>   negative team negates. Resolutions are
>   selected annually by affiliated
>   schools.

Comment: Robusto. Thank you for your answer. Still it bothers me why they use 'Resolution (to be debated)' as defined by Wikipedia in the form of past-participle, "Resolved," which appears to me odd, even before the debate taking place. Is it just a 'normative way' of saying? - Yoichi

Comment: @Yoichi Look at it from this point of view: since you are debating one side of the issue, your position (opinion) is *resolved*, and that is what you are affirming.

Answer (score 2):

In Lincoln-Douglas debate, when a person says something like “Resolved: When in conflict, an individual's freedom of speech should be valued above a community's moral standards,” it means that’s the topic that will be debated.

Saying the word 'resolve' or 'resolved' is actually an abbreviation of the term 'resolution,' which is like saying 'motion.'

If you're debating a subject, imagine you're arguing for a motion to be passed in a vote of some kind. So, you might say "I move to make eating pretzels illegal" or "Motion: to make eating pretzels illegal." Resolution is the same as motion. Saying 'resolved' before a debate represents one debater's stance on the subject either in favor of or in opposition to that resolution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if 'resolved' is being used to mean 'agreed'.
Why is'ahead of' now being used everywhere to mean 'before' or 'ready for' or 'in the light of'? It's very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The word *resolved* stated before the resolution means "obsolete", to deal with successfully, clear up, an immediate course of action, meaning that the plan would immediately be enacted.

Therefore, if you come across a case that involves something like cooperation with other countries or anything that takes a significant amount of time, you can argue that it violates the word *resolved*.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the excerpted use of *Resolved*.

Here is a quote from an online version [Robert's Rules](http://www.constitution.org/rror/rror-01.htm).

> If it is desired to give the reasons for the resolution, they are
>   usually stated in a preamble, each clause of which constitutes a
>   paragraph beginning with "Whereas."
>
> ```
> Whereas, We consider that suitable recreation is a necessary part of a rational educational system; and
>
> Whereas, There is no public ground in this village where our school children can play; therefore
>
> Resolved, That it is the sense of this meeting that ample play grounds should be immediately provided for our school children.
>
> Resolved, That a committee of five be appointed by the chair to present these resolutions to the village authorities and to urge upon them prompt action in the matter.
> ```

In the examples you cite in the second paragraph, I would only agree with the third *Resolved*. The others should use *Whereas*.

In "The United States is losing the War on Terror," the deliberative body is not deciding (or Resolving) to do anything. It is a preamble to a resolution. Same for "The costs of legalized casino gambling in the U.S. outweigh the benefits." These both need a *Whereas* followed by a later "Resolved" and a resolution.

The excerpt provides the decision in "Resolved: The United States should issue guest worker visas to illegal aliens." This is the correct usage.

- Whereas, The usage of *whereas* and *resolved* were established by Brig. Gen. Roberts in 1876, and
- Whereas, Some modern usage of *whereas* has been confused with *resolved*; therefore
- Resolved, That questions be posted to a suitable online forum to inquire as to correct usage of *resolved*.
- Resolved, That authors, legislators, and members of deliberative bodies observe and employ the correct usage of *whereas* and *resolved*.